# Apache POI Compile Error

Tags: apache-poi, jdeveloper

I'm trying to use the Apache POI to write Excel sheets. I downloaded the latest version (3.8) and added it to my project in JDeveloper. I can't get any examples to work. The line:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

give me this error:

```
Error(22,13): Iterable not found in interface org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
  in class org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
  in class test.PoiWriteExcelFile
```

Google is no help. Seems like I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Iterable is an interface first introduced in Java 1.5. POI requires 1.5 or above. Perhaps you are using an earlier version of java or you are not using the SE edition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the poi JAR into your exported files.
To do that, go right click onto your project ->Propreties.
Once there, go to the "Java Build Path" and go to "Order and Export".
Select your poi JAR and move it all the way up.

That should do the trick !